# How to obtain cPacket's originating gate?

Tags: omnet++

Have an object msg (of type cPacket) and I need to obtain the originating gate. How can this be done?

Screenshot of object inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pye8l.jpg

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.
Can you provide an example of what solution have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is depending on the way your module is constructed. In a very easy and simple case you could just use

```
msg->getSenderGate()
```

However, if you have a more hierarchical structure of a module (compound module), you get the gate of the other (simple) module and not the one from the sender in terms of "real network terminology"